Angular Syncfusion PDF Viewer adding second blank page in print preview
I recently started working on a team that shows a number of pdf documents across our angular application. We are having an issue one of these pdf documents is showing an extra blank page in the print preview popup that appears when printing.
In every other window we have that shows this pdf document, there is no extra page. its only showing the extra page in the print preview window when it pops up.
If I go to more settings in print preview and change the scale from default to custom and set it to 99%, then it goes from 1 from to two pages. So how do i make print preview open with it to be automatically scaled to 99%?
I have followed a couple different documentation links that discuss the extra blank page in the print preview https://support.syncfusion.com/kb/article/7566/how-to-avoid-the-extra-blank-pages-in-print-and-print-preview-in-net-webforms-
https://support.syncfusion.com/kb/article/7515/how-to-avoid-the-extra-blank-pages-in-print-and-print-preview-in-net-core-report-viewer-
https://support.syncfusion.com/kb/article/8793/how-to-avoid-the-extra-blank-pages-in-print-and-print-preview-in-js-reportviewer-
https://support.syncfusion.com/kb/article/7617/how-to-avoid-extra-blank-pages-in-print-and-print-preview
these articles are to prevent the extra page from showing when using .net web forms, .net core, javascript, and wpf, respectively. Unfortunately, none of these documents have been able to help me.
I have searched this entire application trying to find out where or how we could be making the width too large on this report that it is causing the extra page to be showing but I cannot find anything.
I even followed this github article i found https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/issues/1431 that gives a great detailed explanation on how to look at styling for CSS media types. Unfortunately for that as well I was not able to see anything specific to the syncfusion pdf viewer that was causing obscure styling issues.
So regardless of the fact that I am not able to see the specific types, lets say I want to change the css styling for all print media in this component. i.e.
@media print {
  * {
    transform: scale(0.99);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
  }
}

ive tried adjusting so many styles to make this work and I, chatgpt, or copilot cannot figure out how to make this page go away when the user first opens print preview
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

i updated the post. if i go to print preview and change it from default to custom scale and change the scale to 99%, then it goes from 2 pages to 1 page. So i tried adjusting the print media for all possible print. I posted the code snippet above. Still, this didnt work. And i tried adjust height, i tried adjust width, setting margin and padding to 0. No change affects it opening with the 2 pages. I put in a ticket with syncfusion, hoping they will be able to give me some more help

If you are experiencing the extra blank page issue in a specific document, kindly share the document in which the issue occurs. This will help us investigate and resolve the issue promptly. Additionally, please share your client and server-side versions.

I just updated the post. first of all, this is only happening in print preview. when looking at the document normally it only shows one page, but when you press ctrl + p or open the print option through code it adds the extra page. I found out this morning if I open print preview and change the scale from default to custom and set it to 99% instead of 100% then it changes the document from 2 pages to 1 page. So i tried changing the styling of all print media as a i posted above, but no matter how i change or adjust the styling it has no affect.

We have logged this as defect as "Extra page appeared in the print preview when print the provided document" and the fix for the issue will be available in our upcoming weekly NuGet release on May 22, 2024. You can track the status of the issue through the following link.
Feedback link:  Extra page appeared in the print preview when print the provided document | Issue Feedback
Disclaimer: "Inclusion of this solution in the weekly release may change due to other factors including but not limited to QA checks and works reprioritization."

We have fixed the reported issue "Extra page appeared in the print preview when print the provided document" and the fix for the reported issue was included in our latest weekly release v25.2.5. Kindly upgrade to that version to get the issue resolved.
